# Could cold Solder be the cause of burnt components?

Tags: soldering, resistance

I have a mainboard of a slot machine that has burnt resistors. I wonder if this could be related to cold solder, because the slot machine remains on for long periods of time (months at a time) and when the power fails, the difference in temperature could cause the solder to fail or become "cold solder". But, could this also cause burnt resistors and capacitors (or other components for that matter) or should that be attributed to voltage peaks?

Comment: It could be in a sense that the not well soldered components are protecting the others from being burnt (like zener diodes, limiting the voltage for example). Or a loose connection can cause some spikes/sparks.

Comment: Your definition of cold solder is wrong. Cold solder joints is when the boards are assembled and the solder is not melted completely during assembly. This can cause an incomplete connection, but is unrelated to the scenario you described. I'd bet the burnt components are unrelated to cold solder, and are probably a result of voltage or current spikes.

Comment: @I.Wolfe Yes, but I would say the solder melts, but does not wet the component lead.  Everything does not get hot.. though it could also be a lack of flux.  (I'm thinking cold solder joints with through hole.)

Comment: So Basically, what we can have is either a failure on a buffer o controler circuit that would save other components from spikes and consecuents burs or spies that burn said components or circuits and then allowing spikes and such. I'm asking because i've been told that using voltage regulators is pointless because burnt components are the effect of switching back on (after power failure) systems that were on for months (all because of this cold soldering ) So is this true? Could be a reason? Would the regulators save my equipment?

Comment: @GeorgeHerold - Ah, I was told that cold solder joints occur when the solder doesn't melt all the way and as a result doesn't wet the component lead well. I meant through hole as well. Chinoka - Solder doesn't fail when it "cools down". As Spehro said in his answer, a component probably overheated or saw a voltage spike which caused it to fail. This would be due to improper ratings/protection. Would probably need a schematic and a list of burnt parts to begin sourcing the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Burned resistors are **not** typically caused by bad solder joints.

More likely a failure of a semiconductor device (due to overheating or voltage spikes) which causes excessive current to flow.

Comment: Ok! So current regulators should be a good thing to use, right?